# How often -if any- are the possessive pronouns "its" or "his" used?

Tags: possessives, possessive-pronouns

How often -if any- are the *possessive-pronouns* "**its**" or "**his**"  used?

Based on many sites and books, the *[possessive pronouns](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc)* for 3rd person singular for people or nouns it's "**its**" (for "it") or "**his**" (for "he") correspondingly.

It means that if I want to say "this car belongs to him.", I can say "the car is **his**.". Or if I want to say that "The lid belongs to this cooking pot." then I can say "It is **its**.". These examples equal to "It is **mine**." (in 1st person singular) or "It is **yours**." in 2nd person singular. No doubt that this is the grammatical form for the *possessive pronouns* (see the table below and the link above to Cambridge dictionary).

**My question is how often we use "its" and "his" as *possessive pronouns*?** 
For this question I found a partial answer in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc) which states: "*We avoid using **its** and **one’s** as possessive pronouns except when we use them with **own**". It seems that except for "its" we don't avoid using other possessive pronoun such as "**his**". But I've never heard someone who say "This is **his.**"  or something like that using "his" as possessive pronoun. Isn't it?

[image]

Comment: "It is its" sounds really weird to me, but "this is his" sounds quite normal.